# Select elements with empty or not-specified attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css-selectors

Take the following, schematic html-code:

```
<div>
  <span id='1' cust-attr='' />
  <span id='2' />
  <span id='3' cust-attr='Foo' />
</div>
```

Now I am looking for a selector finding all `span`s which either do not have an attribute "cust-attr" or whose "cust-attr" value is empty.
In this case, this would be the 1 and 2.

I tried the following selectors with the following results:

1. `span[cust-attr!=]` selects 2 and 3
2. `span[cust-attr='']` only selects 1
3. `span:not([cust-attr])` selects 2
4. `span(:not([cust-attr]),[cust-attr=''])` selects all three
5. `span([cust-attr=''],:not([cust-attr]))` selects 1

However, I did not find one selecting only 1 and 2.
Do you know a possibility?

Note that I want to avoid:

```
span:not([cust-attr]),span[cust-attr='']
```

as "span" is in reality a more complex expression.

Comment: you give us a taste of your complex expression?

Comment: See comment to the answer below - it's for parsing some 3rd-party HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, don't.

It's not good practice to put all your logic into the selector.  It will end up being computationally highly expensive (because the parts need to be parsed out of a string before they are interpreted) and messy.  Use the beauty of the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) method instead:

```
$('span')
    .filter(function(){
        return !$(this).attr('cust-attr');
    });
```

This removes all elements where `cust-attr` is a non-empty string from the selection.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like a nice and clean way.

Comment: huh? This is probably slower, you're constructing a new jQuery instance on every iteration. The selector will be faster in more modern browsers (those that have support for `querySelectorAll`). And what, pray tell, is wrong with `this['cust-attr']`?

Comment: @J-P `this['cust-attr']` is not reliable cross-browser. The way around it would be `this['cust-attr'] != null ? this['cust-attr'] : this.getAttribute('cust-attr')`, but I didn't use that because of excess length. [The speed difference is not enormous](http://jsperf.com/cust-attr).

Answer (score 15):

Late to the party...

... or you could use [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) and be 10x as fast as both jQuery answers... :)

```
document.querySelectorAll("input:not([id]), input[id='']");
```

[Proof](http://jsperf.com/cust-attr/2)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just select all the SPANs first and then filter the selection down? E.g.

```
$('span').filter('[cust-attr=""],:not([cust-attr])')
```

Answer (score 0):

### For modern browser, you can use [`:where()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where) or [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is)

#### *(widely available since 2021)*

Like this:

```css
span:where([cust-attr=""], :not([cust-attr]))
```

or this:

```css
span:is([cust-attr=""], :not([cust-attr]))
```

### The only difference of `:where()` vs `:is()` are the **specificity**

> *[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:where)*
>
> The difference between :where() and :is() is that :where() always has 0 specificity, whereas :is() takes on the specificity of the most specific selector in its arguments.

Using `:where()` will not increase the specificity. Using `:is()` will use the highest selector specificity.

> specificity: `id` > `class` | `attribute` | `pseudo-class` > `element`.

Note: `pesudo-element` selector will not work in both (ie: `::before`).

### Demo

```css
span:where([cust-attr=""], :not([cust-attr])) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

span:is([cust-attr=""], :not([cust-attr])) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id='1' cust-attr="">Text 1</span>
  <span id='2'>Text 2</span>
  <span id='3' cust-attr='Foo'>Text 3</span>
</div>
```